# Difference between Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries or Build Settings -> Linker Flags

Tags: xcode8, build-settings, linker-flags

What's the difference between Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries or Build Settings -> Linker Flags?

The former does not seem to allow you to specify between Debug vs Release, and the frameworks specified within it also don't seem to match up with the latter.

Note: I have checked existing posts on SO, haven't found one that answers this accurately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode translates libraries in `Build Phases – Link Binary With Libraries` into linker flags: `-lsome` or `-framework Some`.

`Build Phases` is a somewhat abstract view on build process. You have this linker step listed here, but it is one-way – it doesn't reveal what is already there for linker in Linker Flags, it only adds new flags to linker.

"Optional" libraries translate to weak linking: `-weak-lsome` and `-weak_framework Some`

Comment: Build Settings has debug and release.  Build Phases applies to which configuration?

Comment: Build Phases applies to all configurations.